# HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 404, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:8087/classes/1", ok: false,

Tags: angular, spring

When I update, I have the error above. Help me please

He are my codes :

1° my classe.component.ts :

```
onUpdateCla(data){
    console.log(data);
    this.classeService.postRessource(this.currentClasse._links.classe.href,data)
          .subscribe(data=>{
            this.mode='list';
            this.onGetAllClasses();
          }, err=>{
            console.log(err);
          });
  }
```

and my classe.component.html :

```
 <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onUpdateCla(f.value)">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label">Nom classe</label>
              <input type="text" name="nomClasse" ngModel
                     class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="currentClasse.nomClasse">
            </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                NIVEAU
                <label >Nivaux</label>
                <select name="niveau" [(ngModel)]="listNiveaux.niveau"  class="form-control">
                  <option *ngFor="let niv of listNiveaux?._embedded?.niveaus" [value]="niv.id">
                    {{niv.nomNiveau}}
                  </option>
                </select>
              </div>
            <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Mettre à jour</button>
          </form>
```

Comment: 404 means that the url is not found...

Comment: the relation between 'niveau' and 'class': 'OneToMany': in a 'niveau' there are several 'classe'.

Comment: I donät understand what that comment means. But as said, 404 means that the url does not simply exist.

Comment: Please post full code as earlier said 404 is page not found/URL not found issue.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you wrote the URL in Service incorrect or there is a problem in the backend. Don't forget that if you are using spring, define the parts with"/" using the RequestMapping.